# Adding value of rows if column A and B cells are similar in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I have a situation. I have three columns

```
|    A    |  B  |   C   |
|Category | Sub | Price |
```

Column A is basically Category column, column B is Sub Category and "C" is price.

I need to add the prices in column C if the category names and sub categories names are Same. Data structure is like below:

```
|A    |B      | C  |
Cat A | Sub A | 100
Cat A | Sub A | 100
Cat A | Sub B | 100
Cat A | Sub A | 100
Cat B | Sub A | 100
Cat B | Sub B | 200
Cat B | Sub B | 100
```

So what I need to add the values for rows with similar A and B and make it one row.

For example, in Excel find all Cat A and Sub A and make one row, add all values of these:

```
Cat A | Sub A | 300
Cat A | Sub B | 100
Cat B | Sub B | 300
```

I used the 'consolidate' option, but it's only taking one left column, so it' not preserving the column B data if I choose the data based on column A.

Please help.

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel, this is exactly what pivot tables are for.

Answer (score 0):

- > You can use **Remove Duplicates** feature to get only unique records.

Select Column A i.e, category and Column B i.e, Sub-Category and use **Remove Duplicates** or use **Unique Records** feature in the Advanced filter. and paste the records some where else.

Here , Don't select Column C i.e, Price

After, You will get Two columns with unique records.

```
cat   sub-cat
---   -------
Cat A   Sub-cat A
Cat A   Sub-cat B
Cat B   Sub-Cat A
Cat B   Sub-Cat B
```

Now, you can use **Sumifs** formula

The second method and simple way is to use Pivot Tables as mentioned in the comments

Comment: thank you @harsha for your suggestion. I used Pivot table that Kyle suggested and it worked like charm. I totally forgot the pivot option :)